# how to delete rows based on a time range in R? Picarro Data

Tags: r, time

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  TIME   | VALVE
10:06:05 |  2
10:06:06 |  2
10:06:07 |  2
10:06:08 |  2
10:06:09 |  2
10:06:10 |  3
10:06:11 |  3
10:06:12 |  3
10:06:13 |  3
10:06:14 |  4
10:06:15 |  4
10:06:16 |  4
10:06:17 |  2
10:06:18 |  2
10:06:19 |  2
```

i want to delete the first 2 seconds of every row everytime the VALVE value changes, but i have no idea on how to do this.

I want my output to look something like this:

```
  TIME   | VALVE    
10:06:07 |  2
10:06:08 |  2
10:06:09 |  2
10:06:12 |  3
10:06:13 |  3
10:06:16 |  4
10:06:19 |  2
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the first 2 seconds of every row?" I see only a timestamp each row. Could you add the expected result?

Comment: You can use: `dplyr::mutate()`, `dplyr::case_when()`, `dplyr::lead()` and `tidyr::fill()`

Comment: @Valentino i added a expected result, sorry for that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, I solved my problem using, `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::mutate` and `dplyr::filter` [based on this post on github](https://github.com/bpbond/R-data-picarro/blob/master/scripts/picarro.R#L35).

First I created a new column and assigned it a number for every time a VALVE changed

```
vnums <- data.frame$VALVE
data.frame$SAMPLENUMS <- c(TRUE, vnums[-length(vnums)] != vnums[-1]) %>%
  cumsum
```

That would give me something like this

```
  TIME   | VALVE | SAMPLENUMS
10:06:05 |  2    |     1
10:06:06 |  2    |     1
10:06:07 |  2    |     1
10:06:08 |  2    |     1
10:06:09 |  2    |     1
10:06:10 |  3    |     2
10:06:11 |  3    |     2
10:06:12 |  3    |     2
10:06:13 |  3    |     2
10:06:14 |  4    |     3
10:06:15 |  4    |     3
10:06:16 |  4    |     3
10:06:17 |  2    |     3
10:06:18 |  2    |     3
10:06:19 |  2    |     3
```

then I:

1. ordered it based on TIME,
2. grouped it by SAMPLENUMS
3. create a column named ELAPSED_SECONDS
4. calculate the elapsed time for each SAMPLENUMS in seconds
5. and then filter out every ELAPSED_SECOND value inferior to 2.

like this:

```
data.frame %>%   
  arrange(TIME) %>%   
  group_by(SAMPLENUMS) %>%   
  mutate(ELAPSED_SECONDS = as.numeric(TIME - min(TIME))) %>%  
  filter(ELAPSED_SECONDS >= 2.0) -> filtered.data
```

and get something like this:

```
  TIME   | VALVE | SAMPLENUMS | ELAPSED_SECONDS | 
10:06:07 |  2    |     1      |       2         |
10:06:08 |  2    |     1      |       3         |
10:06:09 |  2    |     1      |       4         |
10:06:12 |  3    |     2      |       2         |
10:06:13 |  3    |     2      |       3         |
10:06:16 |  4    |     3      |       2         |
10:06:19 |  2    |     3      |       2         |
```

hope it helps.

(damn! i spend more time formatting this answer than working on that DF, whats up with that!?)

Answer (score 2):

the following should work

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(your_data)

fun <- function(x) {
    # function to remove the first two rows
    y <- copy(x)
    y <- y[-c(1, 2)]
    return(y)
}

new_dt <- dt[, fun(.SD), by = .(rleid(VALVE))]
```

Comment: This would not work for `VALVE = 2` in the last 3 rows separately as OP mentions `everytime the VALVE value changes`.  You probably need to use `rleid` as well.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out @RonakShah, I'll edit the answer using `rleid`

Comment: the thing is it has to be a deletion based on time. You'll see, the data frame I depict in the question is an oversimplification, and the first two seconds arent always just the first two rows. i apologize for not clarifying that in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the data shown we can assume you have a reading every second. We can use `rleid` from `data.table` to create groups and remove first two rows from each group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df %>%
  group_by(group = rleid(VALVE)) %>%
  slice(-c(1, 2)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)


# A tibble: 7 x 2
#    TIME  VALVE
#    <chr> <chr>
#1  10:06:07 2    
#2  10:06:08 2    
#3  10:06:09 2    
#4  10:06:12 3    
#5  10:06:13 3    
#6  10:06:16 4    
#7  10:06:19 2
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(TIME = c("10:06:05", "10:06:06", "10:06:07", 
"10:06:08", "10:06:09", "10:06:10", "10:06:11", "10:06:12", "10:06:13", 
"10:06:14", "10:06:15", "10:06:16", "10:06:17", "10:06:18", 
"10:06:19"), VALVE = c("2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"4", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = 
"data.frame")
```